# ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, model, django-errors

Trying to use this Invoice function of first app model (image below)

[First App Model  function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNVFI.png)

Here I am trying to use first app model Invoice function in second app (Image link below)

[Second App view function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWjhb.png)

It show an Import Error (image below)

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmuqG.png)

I am trying to use one app model function in other app model function but it show an ImportError.

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

Each Django App contains an `__init__.py` file, registering them as a package. These "packages" can't import things from other files. To solve this, just put the view function in the same app as the model.